# how to use a separate erb file for a controller free of application.erb rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use a different `.erb` file instead of default `application.erb`, I followed as its stated in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts

I have created a route in routes.rb as

```
get "/vue/v1/" => "vue#vue"
```

a controller as `vue_controller.rb` and its content is

```
class VueController < ApplicationController
  layout "vue"
  def vue
  end
end
```

and in my `view/layouts/`, I also have created a file as `vue.html.erb` so that the controller can use it. The content of `vue.html.erb` is as simple as `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>` but whenever I go to `"/vue/v1/"`, It only gave me error as

```
VueController#vue is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API request. Give it a shot.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are doing wrong is in your controller, you don't have a view for your `vue` action. Try adding a erb file in your `views/vue`

Comment: Okay then what is the use of `layout` in the controller? it's useless?

Comment: Layouts are not your HTML views. Its basically a container in which view is rendered. Give it a try https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html
This will help you understand the concept. Plus you also need a Vue layout in which the actual view will be rendered